# couldn't get exact market place for wp7, where i can upload wp7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have  developed a windowsphone7 app, i used visual studio 2010 and WP7 SDK to develop that app, and i have a registered as developer account.

Now the app is ready to upload in market place,i have the XAP file.

But what the exact problem is i couldn't  get the exact link where can upload my XAP file.

I tried with various search in internet, i can get the link to upload WP8 app but not WP7 app.

That's asking .appxupload file,can anybody give me the exact link, where i can upload my windowsphone7 app(XAP file).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution, actually my account don't have the "**windows phone** developer subscription" have only the "**windows store** developer subscription", i subscribed for windows phone developer subscription, and everything is fine now.I can upload my xap file.

Answer (score 0):

Both WP8 and WP7 apps use the same dashboard.  http://dev.windowsphone.com.  When you upload your xap to the website, it detects and determines which device you are targeting.

Comment: Hi,i got the solution, actually my account don't have the "windows phone developer subscription" have only the "windows store developer subscription", i subscribed for windows phone developer subscription, and everything is fine now.I can upload my xap file.